# Firebase upload image from image picker results in file of octet stream type

Tags: firebase, react-native

Using react native, firebase and EXPO. I am trying to upload an image onto firebase. This is my current idea: Using imagepicker, once the image has been selected, it will be stored as result, in which I am able to get the result.uri and upload onto firebase. This is demonstrated in the code below.

I am trying to upload the image (.jpeg) file chosen from the image picker but have no idea how to do so. I tried uploading result.uri or simply just result into firebase using uploadbytes but the filetype turns out to be 'octet stream', when I change the meta data to image/jpeg, the image cannot be used from firebase.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import { storage } from '../../firebase';
import { auth } from '../../firebase';
import { uploadBytes, ref, uploadStr } from 'firebase/storage';


export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result);
    }
  };

  const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  };
    

  const profileRef = ref(storage, 'user_profile_pictures/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '.png');
  uploadBytes(profileRef, image, metadata).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
  });

  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```